# python_ldap | supplying certificate content in variable

Tags: django, python-3.x, ssl, ldap, python-ldap

I use the following code to supply certificate when establishing a tls connection to a ldap server

`conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE,**PATH_TO_FILE**)`

where PATH_TO_FILE is the path where I have the certificate as a .pem file.But now I am fetching the certificate from the db so the certificate content is available in a variable in my code. I would like to use the variable directly in contrast to having write the data to a file and useing the file path. Is it possible?
I went through the documentation of python_ldap but couldn't find a option which takes the certificate content straight from a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load a certificate from database or whatever variable that is not a file, then write the content of this variable to a file and use that filepath :

```
cert_content = '<dumped-certificate>'
cert_path = '/tmp/cert.pem'
with open(cert_path, 'w') as fp
    fp.write(cert_content)

conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, cert_path)
```